# Active directory disable wallpaper batch

Tags: batch-file, active-directory, wallpaper

I wonder if its possible for a user that has the disabled wallpaper enabled ( this user cant change their own wallpaper), to run a sort of batch command to disable this function? ( so the user is able to set their own ( without any admin permissions and so on) ) .

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible as to make those sorts of changes it would need to be run from an elevated command prompt (which would require that they type the administrator password).